# neo4j - Return single instance of node - querying by property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a social network that has a specialized audience.

Users are related to each other by three primary relationship types.

```
[:FRIENDS]->(:USER), 
[:WORKS_AT]->(:COMPANY), 
[:WORKED_AT]->(:COMPANY), 
[:FOLLOWS].
```

When working through a search scenario (a user wants to find another user), I've given each relationship a "priority" (so to speak).

For example, if a user wants to find another user named "Bart Simpson" - first, we will check co-worker relationships (`[:WORKS_AT],[:WORKED_AT]`). I've assigned those relationships a priority of 1. That way, "Bart Simpson" who works with me will appear in the search results before "Bart Simpson" - who lives hundreds of miles away in Springfield.

The second priority is `[:FRIENDS]->(:USER)`. Do any of my friends have a friend named "Bart Simpson?" Priority #2.

The last priority is a global search. I don't have any co-workers named "Bart Simpson", my friends don't have any friends named "Bart Simpson" - but I met Bart at a conference, and I want to "friend" him. So, I've added a "Global" search. Find any users named "Bart Simpson".

So far, this is my Cypher:

```
optional match (u:USER {id:'1'})-[:WORKS_AT|:WORKED_AT]-(w:COMPANY)-[r]-(f:USER)
with collect(f{.*, priority:1,relationship:r.title,type:type(r)}) as user
optional match (u:USER {id: '1'})-[:FRIENDS]-(:USER)-[r:FRIENDS]-(f:USER)
with user + collect(f{.*, priority:2,relationship:r.title,type:type(r)}) as user
optional match (f:USER)
where f.id <> '1'
with user + collect(f{.*, priority:3,relationship:'',type:''}) as user
unwind user as users 
with users as user
where toLower(user.last_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc') OR toLower(user.first_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc')
return distinct user
```

This is fantastic - however, a user could work at the same company, as well as 
be friends, as well as appear in the global search. So - we have the potential for three (or more) "copies" of the same user - with different relationship attributes. The relationship attributes are important because in the app, they provide important context to the search. "Bart Simpson - Works at XYZ Company."

So what I'm really looking for is the ability to either return the user record with the highest priority - and do that based on the "ID" field. If that doesn't work, I could see a situation where we try to update the property of a node. So, when the query hits the priority 2 search, if there is already a user in the collection with the same "ID", it just appends the P2 relationship type to the record.  Either is fine with me.

I'm open to suggestions and listening!

Answer (score 0):

So, I've made some progress!

```
MATCH 
    (subject:USER {id:'1'})
MATCH
    (subject)-[:WORKS_AT|:WORKED_AT]-(w:COMPANY)-[r]-(f1:USER)
WHERE 
    toLower(f1.last_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc') or 
    toLower(f1.first_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc')
WITH 
    COLLECT(f1.id) AS userIds, 
    COLLECT(f1{.*,priority:1,rType:type(r), title:r.title, detail:w.name}) AS users
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (subject)-[:FRIEND]-(fw:USER)-[r:FRIEND]-(f2:USER)
WHERE 
    NOT(f2.id in userIds) AND 
    (
        toLower(f2.last_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc') or 
        toLower(f2.first_name) STARTS WITH toLower('Sc')
    )
WITH 
    users + COLLECT(f2{.*,priority:2,rType:"FRIEND", title:"Friends with " + fw.first_name + " " + fw.last_name, detail:''}) AS users, 
    userIds + collect(f2.id) AS userIds
OPTIONAL MATCH
    (f3:USER)
WHERE 
    NOT(f3.id in userIds) AND 
    (
        toLower(f3.last_name) starts with toLower('Sc') OR 
        toLower(f3.first_name) starts with toLower('Sc')
    )
WITH 
    users + COLLECT(f3{.*,priority:3,rType:"GLOBAL", title:"", detail:''}) AS users
RETURN  
    users
```

The query has evolved a bit. Essentially, at the first stage, we collect the userIds of the items that were returned. At each subsequent stage, the results returned are compared against the running list of ids. If the id of the result is already in the list of ids, it is filtered out - thus ensuring a unique id in the set.

This is working - and for now, I'm going to run with it. Is this the most efficient query, or is there a better way to deal with this scenario?